# swift calling item from an array with a string

Tags: arrays, swift

I am changing the text of a label in my view controller. It is kind of simple. I have it working when I just call RandomItem, but I want it to say a line of code before I call the Random Item. This is what I have so far.. The code that isnt working is the last line

```
// Generate a random index
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wingmans.count)))
        // Get a random item
        let randomItem = wingmans[randomIndex]
        NameLabel.text = "Your wingman right now is"\randomItem
```

Comment: `NameLabel.text = "Your wingman right now is \(randomItem)"`

Comment: It is called string interpolation.  You can read about it [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Comment: or use string concatenation: `NameLabel.text = "Your wingman right now is " + randomItem`